# Getting a stacktrace & using a debugger with Scheme

Tags: debugging, scheme, stack-trace, festival

I am using `Festival` (the TTS software) and understanding it. It is written in `Scheme` and I am trying to get an execution flow for some of the programs therein. My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a debugger for `Scheme`?
2. How can I get a stacktrace for code written in `Scheme`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Festival uses its own extended version of SIOD that is very small compared to most modern Scheme distributions. There is not much debugging support ([the documentation's page on the subject](http://festvox.org/bsv/x4402.html) is telling) but you may try using [SIOD's documentation](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/scheme-repository/imp/siod.html) on possibly useful hooks.

Comment: Not only that, SIOD is so small and crippled, that calling it a Scheme is questionable.